# Eclipse RCP text editor selection changed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to add a selection changed event to a text editor based on **org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor**.

I would like to get the row(s) and the column(s) of the selected text (when selected/highlighted by the user).

WHats the simplest (if any) way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ITextViewer` object (or the `ISourceViewer` extension) has a `getSelectedRange()` method which returns you a `Point` containing the offset in the document and the length of the selected range.

The `IDocument` object has a `getLineOfOffset()` method which returns the line containing an offset. It also has `getLineInformationOfOffset()` returning information about the line.

So:

```java
Point selected = textViewer.getSelectedRange();

int line = document.getLineOfOffset(selected.x);

IRegion lineRegion = document.getLineInformationOfOffset(selected.x);

int col = selected.x - lineRegion.getOffset();
```